# copy.deepcopy() caused the input value repeated in all the list of the list group, Python

Tags: python, list, copy, deep-copy

```
n = 4 
chessboard_lines_initial = [[0]*n]*n
chessboard_lines = copy.deepcopy(chessboard_lines_initial)
print(chessboard_lines)
#Output: 
#[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]

chessboard_lines[2][2] = 1
print(chessboard_lines)
#Output: 
#[[0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0]]
#However, I was expecting 
#[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

however, if I directly assign [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]] to chessboard_lines, then it works.

Not sure why the copy.deepcopy(chessboard_lines_initial) is not working in this case.

Comment: The deep copy copies the already-wrong structure of `chessboard_lines_initial`.

Comment: When you do `[[0]*n]*n` all the list you are creating are the same. You are just creating 4 references to the same list.

Comment: The duplicate doesn't address why deepcopy works this way. Deepcopy attempts to preserve relationships of shared data in the source into the copy, so you get the same shared structure in the copy

Comment: Thanks! everyone, I was not aware that it was the "[[0]*n]*n" caused the issue!!!! Thanks for pointing that out!